# Distribute ASP.net Application

Tags: asp.net, distribution

I have an ASP.NET application and i selling it to different companies. I change the application settings according to the company information and publish the whole application to a output folder. And then take the output folder to clients machine with necessary dlls(My application dll and few third party dlls). I am wondering if it is possible for anyone to decompile the code from the dll's in bin folder and get the application code? Is there any standard process i need to follow so the my code are safe in client server.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to obfuscate the dlls created for your project, but there are some issues with that related to ASP.NET.  [See this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555355/obfuscating-asp-net-dll-breaks-web-application)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

[Yes](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/asp/soa/Look-inside-NET-DLL-files-with-Reflector/0,339028371,339287377,00.htm).... And see other answers for how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Redgate's [SmartAssembly](http://www.red-gate.com/products/smartassembly/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than Xcopy deploy, you should look have a look at web deployment projects for your deployment - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163448.aspx.

If you need to protect your assemblies from reverse engineering, you need to look at an obfuscator like http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview