# String obfuscation and function names

Tags: vb.net, obfuscation

Can I change the following code and safely obfuscate it ?

or that I must exclude it from obfuscating (e.g. [stackoverflow 2555355 obfuscating-asp-net-dll / 2555497#2555497](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555355/obfuscating-asp-net-dll-breaks-web-application/2555497#2555497) )

```
Dim fontNames As New ArrayList
. . .

Me.myCtrlCmbFontName.DataSource = fontNames
Me.myCtrlCmbFontName.DisplayMember = "mcpGetName"  ' <- Here I get a warning

Public ReadOnly Property mcpGetName() As String    ' <- because of this
  Get
    Return "xxx"
  End Get
End Property
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also asked in
[codeproject 3573871 String-obfuscation-and-function-names](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3573871/String-obfuscation-and-function-names.aspx)

Answer: I need to exclude it from obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

You may have luck if the string value is of a different text case...
try:

```
Me.myCtrlCmbFontName.DisplayMember = "mcpgetname"
```

Comment: Can you please explain how using lowercase helps obfuscation?